# String Format Question - Add two decimal point

Tags: c#, string, decimal

How can I add a decimal point in a string number which has no decimal point at all? and I want it fixed to two decimal places only without rounding it off.

```
  // string x = "341231"; -> 34.1231
  // string y = "31231" -> 31.231
  // string z = "122334124" -> 12.2334124
```

I tried

```
float a = float.Parse(string.Format("{0:n2}",341231); // -> 341231
```

but still the output remains the same. I am doing this for getting the value in for latitude and longitude.

Comment: `string a = float.Parse`?

Comment: ... That won´t even compile. You can´t assign a `float` to a `string`.

Comment: Did you try anything? It doesn't seem to hard to add a period at position 2...

Comment: just take the very two first characters, add a point, add the rest.

Comment: sorry about that, I putted the wrong data type

Comment: A float doesn´t have any formating at all, only strings have.

Comment: the value string came from a file, which I have to put in a string datatype, but I need to extract it as a float data type in order to import it into the database afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why you don't insert a point at your position expected and parse it

```
var x = "341231";
if(x.Length > 1)
     float a = float.Parse(x.Insert(2,"."));
```

Comment: `x.Length > 2`, you dont want a `.` at the end

Comment: as @TimSchmelter said I will just put x.length > 2 instead, thank you for helping out

Comment: @TimSchmelter look at this https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qudlyu . Length == 2 can work

Comment: @ThierryV I see, that's why you just set it to '1'